# SOQL quey to get page layouts Names for perticular object

Tags: apex, soql, sosl

Requirement:I need to find How many **page layouts**(Name) for particular Object using SOQL query or any other method,because I  have 500 objects so i cannot check manually.Please suggest How can i achieve this.
Please response ASAP as its urgent Requirement.

Comment: one of the possible ways would be using workbench -- https://workbench.developerforce.com. Go to Info -> Metadata Types & Components and Select Layout from dropdown. You can see all layouts there per object

Comment: Is there any  way for Perticular object and for the all record type of that object which page layout is associated

Comment: @sukit you can look into this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describelayout_describelayoutresult.htm

Answer (score 3):

We cannot get layout associated with sObject through SOQL.
One has already given an idea to include it in salesforce.
You can find it in salesforce community :- [Link](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KmowAAC)

Hope this will come soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [Layout Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_layout.htm) :

```
SELECT TableEnumOrId, count(Id)
FROM Layout
WHERE ManageableState='unmanaged'
group by TableEnumOrId
```